# Move files from subdirectories into single directory and prefix original directory name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, mv

I have a directory structure like this:

```
./a/1.png
./a/2.png
./a/3.png
./b/1.png
./b/2.png
./b/3.png
./c/1.png
...
```

And I want to take all the files in the subdirectories and move them to a new directory so their names are something like

```
../dest/a_1.png
../dest/a_2.png
../dest/a_3.png
../dest/b_1.png
../dest/b_2.png
../dest/b_3.png
../dest/c_1.png
...
```

The closest I've been able to find without writing a script to do it file by file is to use `find` with the `--backup=numbered` option which would condense my files to a single directory but would end up losing the directory context from the filename.

Is there a succinct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not make a script?

Comment: I did end up writing a (super inefficient) script (in nodejs.. it's what I know best) but was hoping to learn something new :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's|/|_|; s|^|dest/|' */*.png
```

Output:

```
a/1.png renamed as dest/a_1.png
a/2.png renamed as dest/a_2.png
a/3.png renamed as dest/a_3.png
b/1.png renamed as dest/b_1.png
b/2.png renamed as dest/b_2.png
b/3.png renamed as dest/b_3.png
c/1.png renamed as dest/c_1.png
```

If everything looks fine, remove option `-n`.

Comment: Heh, very clever, just replacing `/` with `_` does the job in this particular case, of course.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about Perl `rename` -- looks useful!

Comment: The other approach of Jochen Lutz with `mmv` is also possible: `rename -n 's|(.*)/(.*)|dest/$1_$2|' */*.png`

Answer (score 6):

With Bash 4 and recursive globbing (`shopt -s globstar`):

```
for f in **/*.png; do
  dn=$(basename "$(dirname "$f")")
  bn=$(basename "$f")
  mv -- "$f" "../dest/${dn}_${bn}"
done
```

Note that `dirname /foo/bar/baz` returns `/foo/bar` and not just `bar`, which is why you have to call `basename` on the result to just get `bar` in case you are working from another parent folder.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative approach, you don't need external programs like `rename`, `basename`, etc - it can all be handled within `bash` parameter expansion:-

```
find SourceDir ... | while read -r f; do mv "$f" "TargetDir/${f//\//_}"; done
```

The expansion is a bit difficult to follow, so here's what happens:-

- The files to be moved are found with `find`.
- Each file name is read in turn into `$f`.
- The `read -r` parameter and the double quotes around the expansions handle strange names, including spaces in the file names.
- The `mv` command moves names like `a/b/c` to `TargetDir/a_b_c`.
- The target expansion replaces every `/` by `_`, but it looks daunting because `/` is part of the substitution syntax.
- The general form is `${param/old/new}`, which replaces the first instance of `old` by `new` in the expansion.
- The form needed here is `${param//old/new}`, which replaces *every* instance of `old` by `new` in the expansion.
- In order for `/` to be part of the old string, it must be escaped as `\/`, hence the rather obscure `${f//\//_}`: the first `/` introduces the substitution syntax, the second `/` specifies *replace every*, the third (escaped) `/` is the old string, and the final `/` introduces the new string (`_`).

I don't often see this form of expansion in scripts, but it is worth knowing about, as it can be very useful at times.

There are some file names which will break this (embedded new-line characters, and leading or trailing spaces, though there are two ways round the latter:-

- Use `read -r` instead of `read -r f` and use `REPLY` instead of `f`.
- Use `while f="$(line)"` instead of `read -r f`.

The latter is neater, but uses the external program `line`, which may not be available on all systems, though it can be coded as a function:

```
line() { read -r; r=$?; echo "$REPLY"; return $r; }
```

Comment: Re "it can all be handled within bash parameter expansion", that rather assumes that you're using bash, no?  Whereas Perl &c are shell-agnostic, AFAIK.

Comment: @jamesqf - The questioner included `bash` as a tag, hence the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to **rename**, there is **mmv**, which uses standard shell patterns.

From the man page:

> **Mmv**  moves  (or  copies,  appends, or links, as specified) each source file matching a **from** pattern to the target name specified by the **to** pattern. This multiple action is performed safely, i.e. without any unexpected deletion of files due to collisions of target names with existing filenames or with other target names.  Furthermore, before doing anything, **mmv** attempts to detect any errors that would result from the entire set of actions specified and gives the user the choice of either proceeding by avoiding the offending parts or aborting.

For your use case:

```
mmv -n '*/*' 'dest/#1_#2'
a/1.jpg -> dest/a_1.jpg
a/2.jpg -> dest/a_2.jpg
a/3.jpg -> dest/a_3.jpg
b/1.jpg -> dest/b_1.jpg
b/2.jpg -> dest/b_2.jpg
b/3.jpg -> dest/b_3.jpg
c/1.jpg -> dest/c_1.jpg
c/2.jpg -> dest/c_2.jpg
c/3.jpg -> dest/c_3.jpg
```

Like **rename**, '-n' is no-execute. Remove it for actual renaming.

Besides renaming, mmv also supports copying, linking, or appending the files.